# Is this phrase "now processing..don't terminate this program" correct?

Tags: phrase-requests, programming

I'm developing an application in English, but I'm not a native English speaker, so it's hard to put some English phrases in my app. The following message will appear when my program is processing, so users will have to wait until the process ends.

> Now processing...don't terminate this program.

I don't know if the phrase is used correctly. Can anyone help?

Comment: As several answers have suggested implicitly, you need to include a "please" in there somewhere, or else the message comes across a little rude.

Comment: Sorry to be off-topic, but as a programmer, I'd say that you should design your application so that this message is never displayed. You should always try and provide the user with a 'Cancel' button and you shouldn't design your application so that the integrity of its data is dependent on the user not closing it. As a user, it drives me mad if an application 'locks me out' and the first thing I do with such apps once I've closed them is to uninstall them.

Comment: @tinyd: Absolutely. Any process that may take a significant amount of time to complete should support "cancel", and any "general use" app worth its salt should be capable of recovering after a restart even if the power goes down unexpectedly. But this is UI design, not English language. Voting to close.

Answer (score 2):

In case of application development, avoid using these kind of sentences.

Try `Processing .....` Show a `progress bar` under it
and below write `Please Do not terminate`

Comment: That sounds a bit harsh to me... Also (but that's nitpicking), it's only 3 dots, not 5!

Comment: by 5 dots I want to show progress bar and this is normally the way it is written in case of any application

Comment: As I was saying that was a bit of nitpicking. Anyway I never saw 5 dots in any application, could you provide a specific example?

Answer (score 2):

It is not wrong, but it may be nicer to say something on the lines of:

> Processing... please do not close the program.

or

> Writing data to disk, please do not terminate the program.

or

> Processing... please wait, this may take several minutes.

Comment: The last two examples are run-ons.

Comment: @kiamlaluno: of course, it was just to give some more examples of similar sentences, that can be used in that kind of situation.

Answer (score 1):

I think they usually put it like this:

> Processing...Please do not shut the program.

*Terminate* to me sounds a wee bit technical. *Shut* is kind of easier to understand.

Comment: "Close" is usually used, rather than "shut". They are almost synonymous in English, but the convention in Windows and Mac apps, at least, is "close".

Answer (score 0):

It's not wrong. I'd substitute "the" for "this". I'm guessing your program freezes while processing and you're asking your users not to force quit/kill it? If not, maybe "exit" or "quit" would be better than terminate.

Off topic: as an occasional programmer, assuming your program freezes while processing, I'd suggest a progress bar so that users can see that 'stuff is happening'. Then they're not going to think your program has frozen and terminate it :)

Answer (score 0):

The sentence is not wrong but it has issues. A native English speaker would immediately suspect that the programmer was not a native English speaker.

The ellipsis ("...") feels wrong to me. My instinct would be to simply make it a sentence:

> Processing. Don't terminate this program.

... or use a colon to indicate that the second sentence is a consequence of the first.

> Processing: Don't terminate this program.

"Terminate" is quite a formal word, while the contraction "don't" is quite informal. I'd suggest sticking with formality:

> Processing. Do not terminate this program.

... except that sounds a little rude.

> Processing: Please do not terminate this program.

... and I *think* most users nowadays prefer "application" to "program".

> Processing: Please do not terminate this program.

... and probably they prefer "close" or "quit" to "terminate"

> Processing: Please do not close this program.

In the final analysis, there are an awful lot of nuances even in this very simple prompt.

I strongly suggest you externalise your messages into a message file, and ask someone with strong English skills (either a native speaker, or someone who's lived in an English speaking country for some years) to translate from your native language to English. The translator should also have plenty of experience using your target computer platform, so they know the conventions.